# Grouping DataTable in C# and add duplicated rows in new columns using Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, datatable

I have a data table:

```
ID      Date
-------------
1    02/01/2016
1    03/04/2015
2    08/10/2016
2    01/05/2014
2    09/03/2015
```

I want to use LINQ to group my result like:

```
ID      2016       2015        2014
-------------------------------------
1     02/01/2016  03/04/2015  
2     08/10/2016  09/03/2015  01/05/2014
```

Comment: I am posting questions here for the first time, so its not correctly formatted.Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of your source but something like this would work.

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public List<DateTime> Dates {get; set;}
}

var group = source.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(x =>
        new SomeClass
        {
            ID = x.Key,
            Dates = x.SelectMany(z => z.Dates).ToList()

        });
```

You would group by the ID in your source then add the dates from that ID to the new object.